# flutter : favorite button not change color when pressed

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

When I press it, my button doesn't change color
Does not change color when pressed

```
return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                            child: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () =>
                                    snapshot.data.docs.length == 0
                                        ? addToFavorite()
                                        : print("Already Added"),
                                icon: snapshot.data.docs.length == 0
                                    ? Icon(
                                        Icons.favorite_outline,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )
                                    : Icon(
                                        Icons.favorite,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      )),
                          ),
                        );
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet instead of code image?

Comment: Can you include `addToFavorite()` method too.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a call to `setState()` in your `addToFavorite()` method ?

If not, you must call this function when the `IconButton` is pressed to update your icon by reevaluating your conditions